# requirejs and jquery , nested dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am new to requireJS and I have few questions with ref to my code below where I am using 2 nested require.

1. Where should be the position of `'use strict` , at top of file is ok ? If i move it inside callback function, sublimeText IDE with jshint suggests to move it to top.
2. first require depends on `['jquery', 'bootstrap']` and so does nested require

   (a) so should I add and repeat same dependencies to nested require too ?

   (b) If i don't, what will be impact on grunt or anywhere else ?
3. Should I use `$( document ).ready()` in all files where I am manipulating dom ? even if js files will be loaded on demand

**CODE:**

```
'use strict'; // should it be here ?
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function ($) {
  $('#spinner').show();
  //nested require , should i add parent dependencies 'jquery', 'bootstrap' again below 
  require(['text!app/view/login.html'], function (html) {
    // process html
  });
  //
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 'use strict' at the top of your js file.

Since you are using 'require' not 'define', again loading same thing is not necessary. Once its loaded it will be available for use.

It is not necessary to use $( document ).ready() here as it will load all dependencies first before entering controller.

Comment: One more question please , when starting a single page app, I will once require bootstrap and jquery, For rest of pages I will just require jwuery to get $ and use it , Do i need to add bootstrap again as dependancy in all dynamic pages ? i need to know in terms of optimiser

Comment: load your jquery and bootstrap while initial load itself. It should not be needed to load it again even if you need it